# Batch move lines in a text file based on text

Tags: batch-file

I am receiving a datalogger file that has a one file output. I want to move lines based on a string to multiple text files.

I can get it working with a batch file below but i want to automate it as the text file that the data logger sends always changes its name (with a date)

```
findstr TiltA HMA_input180529.txt >>output.txt
```

**example input** 
csv (*HMA_input180529.txt*)

```
2019-05-29 08:03:48,TiltA,3.420,19.9,0.5017,0.6903
2019-05-29 09:03:48,TiltB,3.420,19.9,0.3017,0.6903
```

**example output** csv (TiltA.txt)

```
2019-05-29 08:03:48,TiltA,3.420,19.9,0.5017,0.6903
```

I dont know where to start in calling all `*.*` files and then saving the new text file to be named the same as the string that was found eg TiltA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with a `FOR /F` loop.

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%i in (%%f) do echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n>"%%j.txt"
)
```

This assumes the format of `token1,TITLE,token3,token4,token5,token6` stays the same.

**OR**

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in (%%f) do type %%f | find /i "%%i">"%%i.txt"
)
```

This assumes the format of `token1,TITLE,*` stays the same.

Comment: Would this still assume that the input text file is always called HMA_input180529.txt though?

Comment: @michaelcrosby That can be changed as you need to, or put it as `%1` and call the batch file from the command line as `name.bat input.txt`. Better yet, you could drag and drop the input file onto the batch file.

Comment: the code works perfectly if i know the file name but i want to run the batch file with a timer so its going to look for any .txt file that comes into the folder every 5 minutes and perform the task. so i really want it to run *.txt as input, but it wont work.

Comment: @michaelcrosby I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in (%%f) do type *.txt | find /i "%%i">"%%i.txt"
)